# Trying to figure out how to pass array object data to a separate method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I wanted to write a program that records bar inventory as I'm a bartender. I can't figure out how to pass the `liquorCost` and `liquorCount` data to the `GetCostTotal()` method below the `main()` method. I'm absolutely sure it's something fairly straightforward that I'm doing incorrectly but I just can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

My `Liquor` class is separate and I can post that if necessary but I don't think it's the class that's giving me the problem, it's retrieving the data input from the array to the separate method.

```
package inventory;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Inventory {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        System.out.println("How many bottles are you taking inventory of?: ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = keyboard.nextInt();
        Liquor[] inv = new Liquor[size];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < inv.length; i++)  {
            inv[i] = new Liquor();
            System.out.println("Enter product name: ");
            inv[i].setLiquorName(keyboard.next());
            System.out.println("Enter the count for the product: ");
            inv[i].setLiquorCount(keyboard.nextDouble());
            System.out.println("Enter the cost for the product: ");
            inv[i].setLiquorCost(keyboard.nextDouble());
        }
        
        System.out.println("The sitting inventory cost of these products is: ");
        //double totalCost = 0
        for (Liquor inv1 : inv) {
            System.out.println(inv1.getLiquorName() + ": $" + inv1.getLiquorCost() * inv1.getLiquorCount());
        }
        
        double costTotal = GetCostTotal(Liquor[] inv, double liquorCost, double liquorCount);        
        System.out.println("The total cost of the inventory is: " 
            + costTotal);
        
        System.exit(0);
        
    }
    
    public static double GetCostTotal(Liquor[] inv, double liquorCost, double liquorCount)  {
        double costTotal = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < inv.length; i++)   {  
            costTotal += (liquorCost * liquorCount);
        }
        return costTotal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        System.out.println("How many bottles are you taking inventory of?: ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = keyboard.nextInt();
        Liquor[] inv = new Liquor[size];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < inv.length; i++)  {
            inv[i] = new Liquor();
            System.out.println("Enter product name: ");
            inv[i].setLiquorName(keyboard.next());
            System.out.println("Enter the count for the product: ");
            inv[i].setLiquorCount(keyboard.nextDouble());
            System.out.println("Enter the cost for the product: ");
            inv[i].setLiquorCost(keyboard.nextDouble());
        }
        
        System.out.println("The sitting inventory cost of these products is: ");
        //double totalCost = 0
        for (Liquor inv1 : inv) {
            System.out.println(inv1.getLiquorName() + ": $" + inv1.getLiquorCost() * inv1.getLiquorCount());
        }
        
        double costTotal = GetCostTotal(inv);
        System.out.println("The total cost of the inventory is: " 
            + costTotal);
        
        System.exit(0);
        
    }
    
    public static double GetCostTotal(Liquor[] inv)  {
        double costTotal = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < inv.length; i++)   {  
            costTotal += (inv[i].getLiquorCost() * inv[i].getLiquorCount());
        }
        return costTotal;
    }
```

Comment: Hey that did it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Lets understand what went wrong here.
Take a look at how you are trying to call the `GetCostTotal()` method.

> double costTotal = GetCostTotal(Liquor[] inv, double liquorCost, double liquorCount);

This is incorrect. The syntax/way you are calling the method is actually used when we what to define a method. Like you did:

> public static double GetCostTotal(Liquor[] inv, double liquorCost, double liquorCount)  {}

Your call should be like:

> double costTotal = GetCostTotal(inv);

Here, we are passing only `inv` because the data for `liquorCost` and `liquorCount` is available inside "each" element of array `inv`.
Now you can accept this argument in `GetCostTotal` method. Here as you are iterating using a for loop, you can read the data you needed as `inv[i].getLiquorCost()` and `inv[i].getLiquorCount()`.

I suggest you can read more on defining a method and calling a method in java.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I understand the mistakes I made at this point and have made a few strides in my understanding of arrays and methods. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help :) I would really appreciate if you could upvote the comment or accept it as an answer.

Comment: unfortunately it looks like I need a rep of 15 to upvote and the other guy already has my answer accepted. I will absolutely come back and upvote once I have the rep though! sorry!